# How do I block installing new apps and internet browing on my Android phone?

Tags: device-administrator

I'd like to be able to block internet access from my Android Pixel 4 cell phone. The ideal solution would prevent me from installing new apps onto my phone. I'd like to have a set of apps, so that I cannot add new apps, such as web browsers. I tried to set this up with Google Family Link, but it will still let you install apps that are rated E for everyone. I also tried this with AppBlock by blocking the app store, but I can download apps from play.google.com from my computer.

I would appreciate any assistance in reaching towards a solution. A potential solution could be one that requires an administrator to have a password to install apps would be acceptable, because I can give that password to someone who isn't me.

I'll note that one possible solution would be to stop internet access with my phone plan. But I'd still like to use the internet for apps like Uber, so that wouldn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: You can add a create a seconds user account and use that account for using your installed apps (only primary user is allowed to install apps).

Comment: Do you mean I create another google account and login on my phone? how do I prevent that user from installing apps?

Comment: @MuhammadHuzaifa this is what Robert meant: https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2865483?hl=en

Comment: @Robert I think this is no longer the case in recent Android versions. In my Android 10 (OnePlus 6), the secondary user can install its own apps.

Comment: You need a kiosk solution. Find a kiosk app in Play Store that suits your needs.

Comment: @Firelord even before Android 10 it's possible to install apps in secondary profiles. But if it's restricted by admin policy you can't. Or admin may allow installations only from managed Play Store (with limited number of packages etc.).

Comment: @IrfanLatif I suppose admin policy is something that is to be created and enforced using something like a device owner app?

Comment: @Firelord exactly.